# PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault in Azure Data bricks

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

I'm trying to access the Azure blob storage in to Azure databricks and when I create a scope and define the sceret key .. after I ran this below code it says no premission denied.. But When i go the Key value of Access Policies ... The access configuration for this key vault is set to role-based access control. To add or manage your access policies, go to the Access control (IAM) page.

dbutils.fs.mount(
source="wasbs://mycontainersrk@mystorageacctsrk.blob.core.windows.net",
mount_point="/mnt/mycontainersrk",
extra_configs={"fs.azure.account.key.mystorageacctsrk.blob.core.windows.net": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="databricks-create-scope", key="dbstorageacctkey")})

Comment: Have you granted databricks permissions on Azure key vault? See step 3 on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes

Answer (score 0):

If the access configuration for this key vault is set to role-based access control

- In **Azure role-based access control**  make sure that you have given
  **Key Vault Administrator** role to your service principal from Access Control (IAM) section of your key vault.
- Or Using RBAC in Key Vault you have to give the "**Key Vault
  Administrator"** role to **Databricks Application**.

**I have below role:**
[image]

**I have tried the below approach:**
[image]

If you couldn't find the Databricks Application when listing its object id in the Key Vault's Access control.

***Note: you should be the owner of the KV inorder add the key vault admin role.***

**You can add role through the Azure CLI:**

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111  --role "Key Vault Administrator" --scope "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}"
```

Know more in detail about [Troubleshoot Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/troubleshooting?tabs=bicep#:%7E:text=az%20role%20assignment%20create%20--assignee-object-id%2011111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111%20%20--role%20%22Contributor%22%20--scope%20%22/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D%22)